# React native admob integration time getting this error

Tags: admob, react-native

I have created a new project. Then, run the project using this command:

> $ react-native run-android`

Then these commands:

> $ install npm install react-native-admob@next
>
> $ react-native link

A refernace is in this link: https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob

Then imported code:

```
import {
  AdMobBanner,
  AdMobInterstitial,
  PublisherBanner,
  AdMobRewarded,
} from 'react-native-admob'
```

Then run the project but I am getting an error that I can't understand. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the keyword `compile` in the gradle config file, change that for `implementation` keyword because the first one was deprecated.

That's all. 
Whenever you add a new dependency to the gradle file use `implementation` keyword.